# MongoDB "Update if Current" of embedded array item using C#

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

In MongoDB, using the C# driver, how can one replace an element of an embedded array ONLY if it hasn't been changed since it was first retrieved. In essence this would be an "Update if Current" of an embedded array element.

For example let's say in STEP #1 I retrieve the following document:

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "4defe15e2a66bc11986859bb"
  },
  "widgets": [
    {
      "_id": "12312312",
      "views": 3,
      "comments": 7
    },
    {
      "_id": "567567FF",
      "views": 0,
      "comments": 1
    },
    {
      "_id": "890TT890",
      "views": 2,
      "comments": 8
    }
  ],
  "dtcreate": "Wed, 08 Jun 2011 16:53:51 GMT -04:00",
}
```

Then in STEP #2 I extract the object of widget "12312312" and make some changes to it so the updated widget is:

```
    {
      "_id": "12312312",
      "views": 5,
      "comments": 9
    }
```

Now in STEP #3 I use the positional operator to update only this specific widget in the document.

Everything here works well, but the only problem is I wouldn't know if another update happened to widget "12312312" between STEP #1 and STEP #3.

What I'm seeking is a clean way to cancel the update in STEP #3 if any update took place to the widget (or even the entire document if it can't be done at the widget level) between #1 and #3.

Answer (score 0):

Better way to avoid concurrent updates it is:

1. Update small parts (not entire widget if it not required).
2. Update some part of document from one place of code with `lock` to make sure that multiple threads not concurrently updating same part of document (it for sure will be bottleneck).
3. Design your database so to avoid concurrent updates of same pieces of a document.

If you need transactions -- use relational databases. Atomic updates is pretty new thing in document databases, many document databases just can load and save documents back.

But, for example, [RavenDB](http://ravendb.net/) support transactions, but transactions (in particular between multiple servers) usually killing scalability. Mongodb goal - scalability and that's mean bye bye [ACID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ACID) and transactions.

[Eventual consistency](http://fredericiana.com/2010/02/17/mongodb-nosql-for-web-applications/) in mongodb:

> MongoDB relies on eventual consistency, not strict consistency. That
>   means, when a write occurs and the write command returns, we can not
>   be 100% sure that from that moment in time on, all other processes
>   will see the updated data only. They will only eventually be able to
>   see the changes. This affects caching, because we can’t invalidate and
>   re-fill our caches immediately, but again, in web applications it’s
>   often not a big deal if updates take a few seconds to propagate

So if you aren't started development with mongodb you can review other databases.

Just make sure that you using right tool for your tasks.

Hope this helps.

Comment: These are good points and I'm aware of most of the strengths and limitations of MongoDB. I've also tried to set up my schema to avoid concurrent updates. However, from my basic understanding of how MongoDB works, I do think (at least hope) there's a solution for this.

Answer (score 0):

This same question was posted here:

http://groups.google.com/group/mongodb-user/browse_thread/thread/888f5e14145d9f0c#

It usually works best when the discussion is consolidated in one place.